# How to know that point lies within geom(Multipolygon) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, gis, postgis

How to know if the point lies within the polygon. I have written the query but somehow it's now working through the point which I have given it's inside the polygon

```
SELECT area, id
st_contains(geom, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-497680.2968362156 7868611.618275354)', 27700))  
FROM soil_shp
where area = 'some_area'
```

PS: I am not getting any errors. Just returning false. Though it supposes to return true in one id.

Can anybody help what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We'd need to know the polygon.

Comment: It's in geometry format. How will I share the geom ?

Comment: Just as it is, EWKB or EWKT.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `area` isn't another geometry:

In order to filter only the records that are inside of a given polygon you have to call `ST_Contains` in the `WHERE` clause.

Consider the following data sample

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
  id INT,
  geom GEOMETRY(POLYGON,4326)
);

INSERT INTO tmp VALUES 
  (1,'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.52 54.29,-4.40 54.29,-4.40 54.25,-4.52 54.25,-4.52 54.29))'),
  (2,'SRID=4326;POLYGON((-4.71 54.11,-4.63 54.11,-4.63 54.09,-4.71 54.09,-4.71 54.11))');
```

[image]

Note: the point inside of the upper polygon corresponds to `SRID=4326;POINT(-4.46 54.27)` and is in the image above just for illustration purposes.

Placing `ST_Contains` in the `WHERE` clause would "discard" the non-overlapping polygons from your resultset:

```
SELECT id FROM tmp
WHERE ST_Contains(geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(-4.46 54.27)');

 id 
----
  1
```